# CE certification of a system containing only ROHS and CE compliant parts

Tags: ce, compliance

As I understand it, if I am self-certifying a device, I can prove my device is compliant by testing or design.

I will be assembling the device using a collection of CE and ROHS compliant components - a vacuum pump, a motor driver, and an AC/DC power supply. I will be adding in a power button to power the array of components on and off and wiring to link the various components together.

Can I claim the device is CE compliant by design, since all parts in the system are CE compliant, assuming the wiring is safely and properly soldered in?

Comment: Is the last sentence a question? Probably not due to EMC.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, machinery directive (Guarding and such to avoid touching rotating or hot components), LVD (touches on mains safety, earthing all that good stuff), EMC (most packaged power supplies (being subassemblies) are not actually required to pass, and motor drivers can be a major can of worms, that is a system level issue for you to solve), then we get to the product specific standards....

Arguably most of these sub assemblies should NOT be individually CE marked.

Self cert is a can of worms.